# Black screen on wince 7 startup

Tags: windows-embedded-compact

I got new motherborad intel gene-bt05 and the BSP.
I built an image nk.bin for wince 7 and then I added it and all the required files to the usb flash drive.
I connected the usb to the motherboard and turned it on but after the loading... screen I got black screen.

can someone halp me please? 
I was looking for a solution but I have not yet found it.

Comment: Hi Eliran, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Your question looks off-topic to StackOverflow. See: [What topics can I ask about here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). I suggest that you move your question to [SuperUser](https://superuser.com/)

Comment: @Elirans, can you share serial port log?